# publishing to Application play store from Delphi community edition 10.4

Tags: android, delphi, google-play

I am a retired disabled programmer who is battling to publish a simple but fun game to the application store.
I am using the Delphi community edition version 10.4 and if I compile to release it works perfectly on all devices that I have tested but if I follow all the instructions to create an aab file to upload to the application store I get the message that the application store requires API 30 whereas community edition 10.4 provides a API 29.
Forcing the target SDK version to 30 allows it to be uploaded to the application store but then it does not work when I download it from the application store.
Can anyone help me please.Thanks

Comment: Of course, Google Play Store requires API 30. 

Have you checked the permissions in your application? 

It would be better for us to detect what is going on if you can share your project deployment settings with us.

Comment: Forcing the API 30 does not give good results, if you can it is better moving to D11

Comment: @Muminjon, are you looking for the data under Projects -> Deployment? If so, how do I copy it here?

Comment: @Muminjon, my project does not need any permissions other than storage read/write

Comment: @mino, I tried installing the 11.1 trial version but project would not compile giving paclient errors not mentioned anywhere on the internet

Comment: I solved it by creating a new project in D11 with the same name, in a different location, with no function, then I close and replace the old files with the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using 10.4 and just loaded app G.P.Store without any problem.
Firstly manually edit AndroidManifest.template.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="%minSdkVersion%" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />

android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="false">
```

Then you have to use Android storage access framework and cancel storage permissions:

Project -> Uses Permissions -> WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE option must be turned OFF even if you need to access external storage files folders Download etc.

If your files are in internal storage only, you dont need any storage permissions already.

More details and sample project available in Github. Search google: **github delphi android saf**

wishing success

Comment: Thank you, emozgun. I initially changed the AndroidManifest.template.xml to force api 30 which allowed me to upload to play store however, downloading from the play store the app will not run and if I try install a release apk with the forced target api and it wont do the install. My apologies, I do not use storage.

Comment: Hi Andy. Can you intimate your mobile android version? As for

Comment: Android 11 RKQ1.201004.002

Comment: Hi, then removing all permissions and trying debug instead of release may help